# SSH key based login bypasses password policies

Tags: ssh, security, password, ldap, openldap

I noticed that logins via an SSH key bypass the LDAP password policies
(password ageing, password warning, and password lockout due to failed
attempts, etc).  Is there any way to force key-based ssh logins to
respect the password policies?

My clients are old (RHEL 4), so installing sssd is not an option.

Comment: Sort of curious why you want it to—those things are pretty specific to passwords. E.g., locked out is to prevent brute forcing a password, but you can't (in practice) brute force a SSH key. And even if you could, it'd be entirely independent of brute-forcing the password.

Comment: Hi, if I connect to the server without using the ssh key exchange and the time to change my password has reached, I'm prompted to do it, so the policy applies, if I user the shared public ssh key to connect, the ppolicy is overriden, I can connect to the server for erver without changing the password, I just was wondering if there is a particular configuration, with pam or ldap as well, to prevent this. cuz in that way, the user would never change their passwords. thanks for your attentiion.

Comment: but you want to enforce the password ageing, lockout, etc on the LDAP password, correct? or are you are trying to control the ssh key password or directly the ssh key?

Comment: @user27238 You can connect to the server w/o changing the password, because you're not using the password. I'm not sure why that's a problem, but you can probably adjust the PAM config to check password expiration in account instead of auth. That may work...

Comment: higuita, the ppolicy works well as long as I do not use the public ssh key, it works as expected, what I'm trying to accomplish is a way to trick the autentication methood to not let me connect using the public key, user27238 suggests to check pam password in account instead of auth. That's what I'm not being able to do. If the time to change my password has been reached, the system has to tell to change it if I connect using the public ssh key exchange. Thanks for your time and attentions. regards

Comment: this is the client configuration, can someone explian why does it work with local users and not with ldap? I mean, if password time has reached and user needs to change it it works whenever is uses public ssh key exchange or not, users who are in ldap with ssh public key exchange can log in anyway. thank in advance. regards.

Comment: auth        required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so likeauth nullok
auth        sufficient    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth        required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_deny.so

Comment: account     required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_succeed_if.so uid < 100 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so
account     required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_permit.so

Comment: password    requisite     /lib/security/$ISA/pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=7 dcredit=-2 ocredit=-2 difok=2 maxrepeat=2
password    sufficient    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so nullok use_authtok md5 shadow
password    sufficient    /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password    required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_deny.so

Comment: session     required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_limits.so
session     required      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_unix.so
session     optional      /lib/security/$ISA/pam_ldap.so

Answer (score 0):

> what I'm trying to accomplish is a way to trick the autentication methood to not let me connect using the public key

You can disable public key authentication with the `PubkeyAuthentication` setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. From `man sshd_config`:

```
 PubkeyAuthentication
         Specifies whether public key authentication is allowed.  The
         default is “yes”.  Note that this option applies to protocol ver‐
         sion 2 only.
```

Your original idea - to force users to change their password when they log in with a public key - doesn't really make sense, because the public key authentication has nothing to do with the password whatsoever. What if it's a script that is using the public key to connect to the server? It can't set a new password. What if a user connects with the public key who doesn't know the password? He can't set a new password because he couldn't supply the old password to the `passwd` prompt.

Comment: Hi Martin, the fact is that, with local authentication, not LDAP in between, the password agging policy work, and eventhough the some users has public key, when the password expires, they are prompted to change it., that's why I do not understand why it doesnt work with LDAP: